# How does facebook single sign-on work under the hood?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-graph-api, single-sign-on

I am using the new javascript sdk and I am developing locally (ie. no hosted server).

I was successfully able to get the access token which the js api stores in a cookie for localhost domain. However what I don't understand is:

- How fb js is able to set a cookie for localhost. Doesn't this violate same origin policy?
- If fb uses Oauth 2.0 protocol for authentication/authorization, how is the single sign-on able to retrieve the access token even when though I haven't specified a callback url and there are no redirect from my main page.

Can someone demystify what is happening under the hood here?

Answer (score 2):

FB JS is able to set cookies on localhost because you're including the FB JS SDK on your domain via a `<script>` tag there by giving them access to your cookies (much the same way Google Analytics writes cookies for your domain).

OAuth 2.0 involves a redirect to your website, there's really no other way for Facebook to return the `code` necessary for your app to retrieve the `access_token`.

Comment: What confused me was that cookies from two domains, facebook.com and localhost, are being set during the flow. The pop-up window is setting the fb.com and the fb js (which is embedded in the orginal document) is setting localhost, right?

about the redirect, how can fb redirect to localhost? My computer is behind a router and I don't even have port forwarding enabled for the localhost server. Could something else be going on here?

Comment: Yes, you're correct - the JS SDK is setting cookies on localhost, and the popup to facebook.com sets it's own cookies (though not always). The reason Facebook can redirect to localhost is because a redirect does not involve a _connection_ from the source (facebook.com) to the target (localhost), and instead only involves instructions for the browser to make that connection. Something like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) might help make this much clearer in a more obvious way.

Comment: I am confused by how this is an Oauth flow (as fb claims it is). In a 3-legged flow, the provider makes a callback to the server where the server side code parses the access_token from the url and redirects to the original client UI state. Things are somehow different in the single sign-on flow. There is no server side interaction. The fb js launches a new window (fb.com domain) where the user authorizes the app. Then this window automatically closes, the control goes back to the orignal window and magically the access token appears in the cookie. How did the orignal parent get the cookie?